# Changing Images src with Event "onclick"

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id = "imageOne" src = "circleRed.png" onclick = "changeColor()"/>

<script>
var image =  document.getElementById("imageOne");

function changeColor() {
if (image.src == "circleRed.png") {
    image.src = "circleBlue.png"; 
} else {
    image.src = "circleRed.png";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This whole program may seem to work but no. I'll just be able to change the color of my image once. After clicking for the second time, nothing happens. What I mean is that I can only change the color from Red to Blue.
Could you please help me figure out why?

Comment: you are missing closing `}` . it just a typo right ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi yeah it's just a typo, sorry

Comment: you can check like this `image.src.indexOf( "circleRed.png")>-1` .. it's mean image is circleRed

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi oh okay. By the way, what do you call the "indexOf"? is it an attribute?

Comment: indexOf is an extension method . it'll check if this contain in a string or and array.. If it contain it'll return the index else -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <img id ="imageOne" src ="circleRed.png" onclick = "changeColor()"/>

        <script>
            var image =  document.getElementById("imageOne");

            function changeColor()
            {
                if (image.getAttribute('src') == "circleRed.png")
                {
                    image.src = "circleBlue.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    image.src = "circleRed.png";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why this would work? and why does mine not work?

Comment: because image.src return the full path of the image so comparing is going to false and when you use getAttribute('src') it will return the file name and comparison will return true

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = document.getElementById("imageOne");
```

Move this inside function before if statement

Comment: Try moving script tag to head section and specify type attribute for script tag

Answer (score 0):

`image.src` returns the physical path of image. So you can use `indexOf` to match image name. Following code snippet may help you.

```js
function changeColor(image) {
    if (image.src.indexOf("circleRed.png")>-1) {
        image.src = "circleBlue.png"; 
    } else {
        image.src = "circleRed.png";
    }
}
```

```html
<img id = "imageOne" src = "circleRed.png" onclick = "changeColor(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this code. just make sure to use (img.src.match)**
.**And script inside the body.**

```
var img = document.getElementById("image1");
img.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
      if(img.src.match("images/image1.jpg")){
           img.src ="images/image1_2.jpg";}
       else {
           img.src = "images/image1.jpg"
            }  
})
```

`<img src="images/image1.jpg" id="image1" />`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeColor(image) {
    if (image.src.indexOf("circleRed.png")>-1) {
        image.src = "circleBlue.png"; 
    } else {
        image.src = "circleRed.png";
    }
}
```

```html
<img id = "imageOne" src = "circleRed.png" onclick = "changeColor(this)"/>
```