# add different image in same button

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I have a round button and i want to add a image in it and change that image into another image when clicked in same button.

let the image seen in button at first br "a.svg", and image seen after clicking the button be "b.svg".
this is my little code:

```html
<div class="btn" style="float: right;">
<button class="showhide"><img></button></div>
```

I think we should do some javascript, i want your help and i don't want jquery for this.

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102091/changing-images-src-with-event-onclick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in JQuery using a simple flag to work out which image to show.

The snippet below shows this in action:

```js
var img = 0;

$('.showhide').click(function (e) {
  setImage();
});

function setImage() {
  var src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150';
  if (img++ == 1) {
    img = 0;
    src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/200';
  }
  $('.showhide > img').attr('src', src);
}

setImage();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" style="float: right;">
<button class="showhide"><img></button></div>
```

Essentially, when clicking the button the image is switched between the two defined images.

You can extend this very easily to use image sources from an array rather than hard-coding this it a single image:

```js
var img = 0;
var images = [ 'https://via.placeholder.com/150', 'https://via.placeholder.com/200', 'https://via.placeholder.com/250' ];

$('.showhide').click(function (e) {
  setImage();
});

function setImage() {
  if (img > images.length - 1) {
    img = 0;
  }
  $('.showhide > img').attr('src', images[img++]);
}

setImage();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" style="float: right;">
<button class="showhide"><img></button></div>
```

**OP Comment: i want it in javascript not in jQuery please**

For a pure JS solution without JQuery, just modify the JQuery elements to their composite JavaScript ones:

```js
var img = 0;
var images = [ 'https://via.placeholder.com/150', 'https://via.placeholder.com/200', 'https://via.placeholder.com/250' ];
var showHide = document.getElementById('showhide');
var showHideImg = document.getElementById('showhideimg');

showHide.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  setImage();
});

function setImage() {
  if (img > images.length - 1) {
    img = 0;
  }
  showHideImg.src = images[img++];
}

setImage();
```

```html
<div class="btn" style="float: right;">
<button class="showhide" id="showhide"><img id="showhideimg"></button></div>
```

Comment: i want it in javascript not in jQuery please @Martin

Comment: @Aarzu I've added a pure JS implementation of the same for you

Comment: sorry but now i want it in as image only not in button please forgive me :);
```
                <img id ="imageOne" src="eye-solid.svg" alt="" style="width: 10%; height: 10%; float: right;" onclick="changeColor()">
```
and js
```
 var image =  document.getElementById("imageOne");

        function changeColor()
        {
            if (image.getAttribute('src') == "eye-solid.svg")
            {
                image.src = "key.png";
            }
            else
            {
                image.src = "eye-solid.svg";
            }
        }
```

Comment: please help me @Martin

Comment: @Aarzu I think that's a different question; I've answered the one you already asked. Please add a new one and I'll try to help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427288/change-image-when-clicked-in-img-using-javascript please help me  @Martin

Comment: it is not working for images of my own in for eg i have image "eye.svg" and "eye2.svg" how can i display it? @Martin?

Comment: @Aarzu As you can see, the snippet above definitely works, so I presume you've changed something when copying the above code.  Please paste what you have done.  You shouldn't mark as unanswered a working solution that you already accepted

Comment: I replaced 'https://via.placeholder.com/150' with 'eye.svg' and it is not working

Comment: will you please set some events(disable some text of paragraph) when clicked in 1st image and set those text visible when clicked in second image?