# Change looping image source with OnClick method

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I swap the `src` of an image with a different one when the image is clicked? I tried with the below code:

```
function changeImage() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage[]');
  }
  if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
    image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
  } else {
    image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
  }
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) { ?>
<img id="myImage[]" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
<?php } ?>
```

I want if **myImage[]** clicked, the source change to *pic_bulbon.gif*,
if i click again the source change to *pic_bulboff.gif*.

How can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Images src with Event "onclick"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102091/changing-images-src-with-event-onclick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this` to `changeImage` so get the clicked `img`, then check its `src`, and use the conditional operator to either assign `bulboff` or `bulbon` to its `src`:

```
<img id="myImage[1]" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
<img id="myImage[2]" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
```

```
const changeImage = (img) => {
  img.src = img.src === "pic_bulbon.gif" ? "pic_bulboff.gif" : "pic_bulbon.gif";
};
```

But it would be better to avoid inline handlers entirely - attach the event listeners properly using Javascript instead:

```
<img src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
<img src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
```

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((img) => {
  img.addEventListener('click', () => {
    img.src = img.src === "pic_bulbon.gif" ? "pic_bulboff.gif" : "pic_bulbon.gif";
  });
});
```

Live demo:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((img) => {
  img.addEventListener('click', () => {
    img.src = img.src === "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=foo" ? "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=bar" : "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=foo";
  });
});
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=foo" width="100" height="180">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=foo" width="100" height="180">
```

Comment: Is it work for image looping?, sorry, i changed my question

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" - you can see it working for yourself.

Comment: Thats work, but when the source change to pic_bulbon.gif, it can not change to default again (pic_bulboff.gif), can you explain?

Comment: Sure it works - if you click the image again, it will switch. Press "Run code snippet" in the answer to see. If you click once, the image changes. If you click it again, the image changes back.