# How to jsx image click image change

Tags: reactjs, jsx

If you click the current image, you will see a different image, and if you click again, please return to your original state...

I tried other codes several times, but it didn't work. I ask for your help.

```
function Login() {
   const [loginCheck, setloginCheck] = useState('./images/Login/login2.png');
    
   const checkboxToggle= () => {
   setloginCheck('./images/Login/login1.png');
  }

  return (
  <>
    <img
    className="loginCheckbox"
    src={loginCheck}
    alt="체크박스"
    onClick={checkboxToggle}
  />
  </>
  );
}
```

Comment: you could add a function in your login that uses your setState function. you have the right idea regarding checkboxToggle, however all it does is set the local state to the login1.png. A simple if-else for comparison reasons would allow you to change the state according to the way you want it. Also check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102091/changing-images-src-with-event-onclick) out as it shows how to do what you request using the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm learning a lot. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store your images in an array and store the currently displayed index into a state.
For two images a boolean would do the job, but using this approach would work also in the case of having more than 2 images:

```
function Login() {
  const images = ['./images/Login/login1.png', './images/Login/login2.png'];
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);

  const checkboxToggle = () => {
    setImageIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % images.length);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <img
        className='loginCheckbox'
        src={images[imageIndex]}
        alt='체크박스'
        onClick={checkboxToggle}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about putting the pictures in the arrangement.
I'm learning a lot. Thank you.